# File copy in ansible failed! =>{"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'files'"}

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to find files with .ign extension from a directory and copy it to another directory. Tried using the 'find' and 'copy' module as follows:

```
- name: Find files
  find: 
    paths: "{{ item }}"
    recurse: yes
  register: find_result
  with_items:
    - "{{ workdir }}/*.ign"

- name: Copy files
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: "/var/www/html/ignition/"
    mode: o+r
    remote_src: yes
  with_items: "{{ find_result.files }}"
```

`workdir` is set as `/root/openstack-upi`. And I am running this as a non-root(cloud-user) user with the command--

```
ansible-playbook  -i inventory -e @install_vars.yaml playbooks/install.yaml --become
```

However, after running this I get an error as below:

```
TASK [ocp-config : Find files] ***************************************************
ok: [ash-test-faf0-bastion-0] => (item=/root/openstack-upi/*.ign)

TASK [ocp-config : Copy files] ***********************************************
fatal: [ash-test-faf0-bastion-0]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'files'"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
ash-test-faf0-bastion-0    : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Running a debug on variable `find_result` gives the following-

```
"msg": "/root/openstack-upi/*.ign was skipped as it does not seem to be a valid directory or it cannot be accessed\n"
```

Am I missing anything here? Can anybody tell me the exact command for the ansible-playbook for the above scenario?

Comment: If you're unsure what keys is available in your dictionary (`find_result`), please consider printing it out using `debug`.  Though when you use `with_items` with `register` your results is usually saved in a list (`results`) of dictionaries (`find_result.results[X].files`). And a final thing, I do think `with_items` only accepts when you have a pre-defined value to give it, e.g a list. Consider looking at the `with_fileglob: directory/*`

Comment: Remove the loop in your first task. It's useless in this situation and makes ansible register each loop as an element of a `results` key which will force you to loop twice (once on `results` then on the contained `files`). This is why you actually get an error. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution will does not use the `with_items` option. It will recursively find all the files which ends with the extension/suffix `.ign`.

```yaml
      - name: Find files                                                         
        find:                                                                    
          paths: "/path/to/directory"
          patterns: "*.ign"                                             
          recurse: yes                                                           
        register: result                                                         
                                                                                 
      - name: Print find result 
        debug:                                                                   
          msg: "{{ item.path }}"                                                 
        with_items:                                                              
          - "{{ result.files }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

An explanation regarding your given find file loop

```yaml
  with_items:
    - "{{ workdir }}/*.ign"
  register: find_result
```

and the given error message

```
msg": "/root/openstack-upi/*.ign was skipped as it does not seem to be a valid directory or it cannot be accessed
```

It will be necessary to lookup the files matching a pattern before. This can be done with the [`with_fileglob`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html) lookup plugin.

```yaml
  with_fileglob:
    - "{{ workdir }}/*.ign"
  register: find_result
```

or better and as explained in [the accepted answer here in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845319/6771046).

The error message just sayed the path and filename were skipped as `.../*.ign` wasn't a valid path and filename. It means it hasn't looked up any files and hasn't resolved the fileglob.